# Gradle Dependency loading from maven

Tags: maven, dependencies, gradle

I am new to gradle.

I have seen some examples about java dependency like the following example but my project will be simply a zip file.
I just want to download the zip file.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
}
```

In the above example, it will automatically download the jar file. But it doesn't download my zip file if my maven repositories contains zip that mentioned in the pom.xml about that package.

Questions:

1. What is the flow when depend on a maven repository? It will first read the pom.xml and then download the zip file?
2. How to dynamically load the dependency? e.g 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6' will have dependency of 'commons-lang:en:1.0" in the pom.xml. How to make it automatically load and loop the dependency list?

Thanks all

I have tried the follwoing script but it gives me error on compile but I have apply the java plugin

My gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "http://nexus.com/myrepo/"
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.a.b:projectA:2.0@zip'
}
```

I can run without problem that files downloaded are inside .m2

Question about the transitive dependency

I have the pom.xml like this. But it is unable to load the dependency one. It will directly go to the new pom.xml first or download zip directly if i mention sth like this?

```
   <dependencies> 
         <dependency>
              <groupId>com.a.b.c</groupId>
              <artifactId>base</artifactId>
              <version>1.2</version>
              <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- When declaring a dependency and a maven repository, this maven repository will be used to resolve the artifact. this means that usually first the metadata is read and then the artifact will be downloaded. If no repository is declared the resolution will fail early.

Having a dependency notation like yours:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
}
```

gradle resolves the default artifact of that dependency. If you want to resolve additional declared zip files from maven central, you have to use this notation

```
repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6@zip'
}
```

- As a default, the a dependency is transitive. This means, that if e.g 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6' has a dependency on 'commons-lang:en:1.0" in its pom.xml the commons-lang library (and again its transitive dependencies if any) is also resolved.

cheers,

René

Comment: Thanks.So it will read pom.xml first and then download the artifact. But I have tried similar on above code. I have no idea why it says compile is not available.
In the above test, my classpath 'com.a.b:project:1.0' work but compile 'com.a.b:projectA:2.0@zip' doesn't work.

Comment: have you declared a repository? see my updated answer

Comment: ya.I have already added. But i can't find any files downloaded. My build.gradle is updated in my question

Comment: use mavenLocal() instead of mavenCentral() to resolve from ~/.m2/repository. If you have a custom repo directory have a look at the gradle user guide to see how to configure custom repositories

Comment: Thanks.It works but another question about the transitive. Default of transitive is true, right? I have already set the dependencies, but it doesn't work. Is it just for java only? I have updated my pom.xml for your reference

Comment: when using explicit package notation `com.a.b:projectA:2.0@zip` the the dependency is not throated as a maven dependency anymore, which means, that the pom is not evaluated anymore and because of that no transitive deps are calculated & resolved.

Comment: thanks very much...if i don't set @zip in the gradle,but set in the pom.xml, it will aslo download the zip package...thanks